# GAN - loss and evaluation of model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm struggling with understanding how to "objectively" evaluate a GAN (that is, not simply look at what it generates saying "this looks good/bad").

My understanding is that the discriminator should get a head start and, in theory, discriminator loss and generator loss both ought to converge to 0.5 - at which point both are equally "good".

I'm currently training a model, and I get discriminator loss beginning at 0.7 but quickly converging toward 0.25, and generator loss beginning at 50 and converging toward 0.35 (possibly less with further training).

This doesn't entirely make sense. How can both be better than 0.5?
Are my loss functions incorrect, or what else am I missing? How should performance be measured?

Answer (score 2):

In a GAN setting, it is normal for you to have the losses be better because you are training only one of the networks at a time (thus beating the other network).

You can evaluate the generated output with some of the metrics *PSNR*, *SSIM*, *FID*, *L2*, *Lpips*, *VGG*, or something similar (depending on your particular task). This is still an ongoing area of research on how to objectively evaluate an image, and they are generally used as loss objectives in certain tasks.

I recommend looking at something like [Analysis and Evaluation of Image Quality Metrics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-81-322-2247-7_38#:%7E:text=Image%20quality%20measures%20like%20Mean,thoroughly%20discussed%20in%20this%20paper.)

I would recommend you look at the generator metrics over time to see if its improving, and obviously confirm that visually as well. You can use logging to see the metric changes or some visualization tools, tensorboard, or wandb for this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and links. I see that I was missing that since each model is trained separately, their losses are also calculated independently of each other.